# Sort paths by date - Utility method

Tags: java, sorting, path

Is there any utility class in some package like commons-io,jodatime etc , where one could pass in a list like:

```
March/Invoice - 00000020 - 01.03.2013.xls
March/Invoice - 00000021 - 08.03.2013.xls
April/Invoice - 00000025 - 05.04.2013.xls
January/Invoice - 00000015 - 25.01.2013.xls
```

and get the paths sorted by months like:

```
January/Invoice - 00000015 - 25.01.2013.xls
March/Invoice - 00000020 - 01.03.2013.xls
March/Invoice - 00000021 - 08.03.2013.xls
April/Invoice - 00000025 - 05.04.2013.xls
```

We could probably write a `Comparator` ourself, but I was hoping something like this already exists in some third party library ?

Comment: not that i know of. seems simple enough with some Regexp and a Calendar though.

Comment: You can write a Comparator by youself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is better than searching for any third party library , I believe :

```
final Map<String, Integer> monthMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
// Initialize it with all the months and corresponding index like:
// (January,1), (February,2), etc...
monthMap.put("January", 1);
monthMap.put("February", 2);
monthMap.put("March", 3);
monthMap.put("April", 4);
monthMap.put("May", 5);
monthMap.put("June", 6);
monthMap.put("July", 7);
monthMap.put("August", 8);
monthMap.put("September", 9);
monthMap.put("October", 10);
monthMap.put("November", 11);
monthMap.put("December", 12);

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b)
    {
        String first = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(File.separatorChar));
        String second = b.substring(0, b.indexOf(File.separatorChar));

        return monthMap.get(first).compareTo(monthMap.get(second));
    }
});
```

I believe there can be a better solution than this , it is just a pointer .

Comment: Thanks for the rough example. I sort of re-worked it, I hope you don't mind.